# Есть ли поддержка общения с ботом в Telethon Python?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Мне нужно парсить данные с бота на библиотеке Telethon (Python).
Есть ли поддержка отправки и получения сообщений от бота telegram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример кода для отправки сообщения боту:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient

api_id = <ваш API ID>
api_hash = '<ваш API хеш>'
phone_number = '<номер телефона, привязанный к аккаунту>'

with TelegramClient('my_session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.start()
    result = client.send_message('@my_bot_username', 'Привет, бот!')
    print(result)
```

Пример кода для получения сообщений от бота:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import events

api_id = <ваш API ID>
api_hash = '<ваш API хеш>'
phone_number = '<номер телефона, привязанный к аккаунту>'

with TelegramClient('my_session', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(from_users='my_bot_username'))
    async def handler(event):
        print(event.message.text)

    client.run_until_disconnected()
```